# How to code a button to direct to another webpage and check a checkbox

Tags: javascript, forms, redirect, button, checkbox

I'm working on a simple html boostrap project and need a button (href or button) on my index.html that when I click it, it sends me to my contact.html page and check a checkbox. I'm making a list of products and when visitors see the item they want and click it, it can directs them to the contact page with the item already marked to complete the information for purchase (checking a checkbox). I'm very basic on html and css and have a nule knowledge about js, and I imagine that it can be done with a function, but haven't found a similar question anywhere to implement it.

In my own poor knowledge I have tried to direct my button to contact.html#item1 (where item1 represents the checkbox I want to be checked), obviously with no results.

This is part of the code I have (i have take out the divs and img tags to simplify the code):

```
<a href="contact.html#item1">I want popcandy!</a>
<a href="contact.html#item2">I want icecandy!</a>
<a href="contact.html#item3">I want spicecandy!</a>
```

And the buttons in the form of the contact.html page are something like this (the ones I needed to be checked with the above buttons):

```
<input id="item1" type="radio" name="item1" value="item1"/><label >Popcandy</label>
<input id="item2" type="radio" name="item2" value="item2"/><label>icecandy</label>
```

If you have any solution please let me know, I'm very grateful. Sorry for my english redaction mistakes. :)

Answer (score 0):

You would want to add a query string to your href for the button, and then check that query string when the destination page loads.

`href=‘contact.html?checkItm=item1’
href=‘contact.html?checkItm=item2’`

Then in response to the page load event on the contact.html page, check the query string parameter checkItm and use JavaScript to check the appropriate item.

See this question for examples of how to check a checkbox from url query string. [selecting checkboxes based on url parameters](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/172348/selecting-checkboxes-based-on-url-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a anchor text:

```js
var href = window.location.href;
var anchor =  href.substring(url.indexOf("#")+1);
```

2. check input with anchor text:

```js
var item = document.getElementById(anchor)

if (item) {
  item.checked = true
}
```

Below code shows how it works.

```js
var anchor = 'item2'

var item = document.getElementById(anchor)

if (item) {
  item.checked = true
}
```

```html
<input id="item1" type="radio" name="item1" value="item1"><label for="popcandy">Popcandy</label>
<input id="item2" type="radio" name="item2" value="item2"><label for="icecandy">icecandy</label>
```

Comment: Thank you Zmag, however maybe I didn't explain myself right. I want one button or hyperlink or even a checkbox button that when clicked it sends me to another webpage and checks a checkbox of that page. So if i have item1, item2 and item3 buttons on "webpage1.html" if I click on item2 it sends me to the "webpage2.html" and check the checkbox named item2. I imagine it needs some js code for the "webpage1" and some js code also on "website2."

Answer (score 0):

Process `location.hash` on `contact.html` page. Something like this.

```
window.onload = function(){
   if(location.hash){ // hash (#item) exists
     var hash = location.hash.replace('#','');
     var item = document.getElementById(hash);
     if(item){
       item.checked= true;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex but I don't understand how can I process it, would be like? 
On index.html:
    <a href="contact.html?checkItm=item1">popcandy</a>

On contact.html:
    <input id="item1" type="radio" name="item1" value="item1"/><label >Popcandy</label>

And the script in contact.html:
    <script>
    window.onload = function(){
       if(location.hash){ // hash (#item) exists
         var hash = location.hash.replace('#','');
         var item = document.getElementById("item1");
         if(item){
           item.checked= true;
         }
       }
    }
    </script>

Comment: Add `script` block on `contact.html` page. `location.hash` is what goes after `#` character in the URL.